# What does it mean to have a settling time at 5% of final value?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, time, tolerance

I need to make my control system to have a tolerance of 5% in less than 0.5 seconds (settling time t<sub>s</sub> = 0.5s at 5%).

My question is: does 5% mean the error band can be between these values in red (assuming unit step input)? Or can it be between 1.05 and 0.95 (or is that when the tolerance is 10%)?

[image]

Comment: Within 5% of final value usually means +/- 5% of the final value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always ask whoever wrote the spec/requirement, but typically N% tolerance means nominal value +/-N%. So the tolerance band is 2N% wide.